# Paralist : right shift with big labels

Tags: lists, paralist

In paralist, one can adjust the room for large labels on the fly, but can it be done directely in the `\setdefaultenum` command ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\setdefaultenum{\bf 1.}{a)}{\it i.)}{}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactenum}
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item \textcolor{red}{Right shift}
\end{compactenum}

\begin{compactenum}[\bf 1.][10]
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item Bla
\item \textcolor{blue}{Ok}
\end{compactenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If it doesn't do a two-pass algorithm, I don't think it is possible.

Comment: It seems to do it on the fly like in example. But why has it to do a two pass algorithme as the right right shift is known in advance?

Comment: If you know in advance the number of items, you can do it, as shown by the second example. Otherwise you need to record the number of items at `\end{compactenum}` and use this at the next run.

Comment: It's not the number of items but the wider you imagine to have. In example in the doc one take 8 as viii is the wider untill xvi (see p4).

Comment: you have to scan all labels for the widest entry then apply the shift in the second pass during the actual typesetting.

Comment: I understand and thank you for this help, but the question is a syntax problem : how to set this widest label in the `setdefaultenum` in the preambule instead of on the fly in the `begin{enumerate}`, if it is possible ? It's not of an absolute necessity, but I asked myself if it is possible. Don't spend much time on it.